# My switch statement won´t let me use a particular variable as an expression

Tags: c++, switch-statement

What I want is for it to let the user guess the number as many times as it takes to guess it, then tell him the number of times it took him to guess it, that´s why im making the condition for the for loop g!=r, however, I have no idea if C++ allows this.

Also, the errors I get when trying to compile this are

```
expression must have a constant value 

expression did not evaluate to a constant" and "case expression not constant
```

Here´s the code:

```
int main()
{
    int r = rand() % 101;
    int g = 0;
    int t = 10;

    std::cout << "Guess a number, human (From 1 to 100)." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> g;

    for (int t = 0; g != r; t++)
    {
        switch (g) {
        case (g == r):
            std::cout << "You won, now get lost!" << std::endl;
            break;
        case (g < r):
            std::cout << "Too low, piece of turd." << std::endl;
            break;
        case (g > r):
            std::cout << "Too high, dubai." << std::endl;
            break;
        default :
            std::cout << "How could you possibly have gotten it wrong, you stupid ape." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Finally!, it took you " << t << " freaking times!" << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Switches only let you test for equality to a specific value, not to a range.  You can say switch (g) { case(r): .. } but not g > r or g < r.   Just use a series of if/else if statements instead.

Comment: This code should be written as `if (g == r) ... else if (g < r) ... else if (g > r) ... else ...;', although the final `else` clause will never be executed.

Comment: You can't even say `case r`, @Jeff. The case expressions need to be compile-time constants.

Comment: _"piece of turd"_ Really?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need all the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Comment: You haven't asked an actual question, and you aren't using a particular variable as an expression, you're using several particular expressions as constant-expressions when they aren't constant. You should have paid more attention to the actual text of the compiler errors, rather than jumping to conclusions.

Comment: ok, so, I forgot to add the std::cin  << g; lines to the cases that I need so that the user can try to guess again, but anyway, i changed it to a set of if statements,  and now after the first guess, the user isn´t able to guess again.

Comment: ill post the code in a sec.

Comment: my question is, why won´t it do what I want it to do?

Comment: int main()
{
 int r = rand() % 101;
 int g = 0;
 int t = 10;
 std::cout << "Guess a number, human (From 1 to 100)." << std::endl;
 std::cin >> g;

 for (int t = 0; g != r; t++)
 {
  if (g == r)
  {
   std::cout << "You won, now get lost!" << std::endl;
   std::cin >> g;
  }
  else  if (g < r)
  {
   std::cout << "Too low, piece of turd." << std::endl;
   std::cin >> g;
  }
  else if (g > r)
   std::cout << "Too high, dubai." << std::endl;
   std::cin >> g;
 }
 std::cout << "Finally!, it took you " << t << " freaking times!" << std::endl;


 return 0;
}

Comment: uh, sorry, still new to all this, ill edit my last comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're required to use a switch, you might try using a while loop with a flag and some checks before the switch:

```
bool flag = true;
int t = 0;
int x = 0;
while( flag )
{
        t++;
        std::cout << "Guess a number, human (From 1 to 100)." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> g;

        if( g == r )
        {
           x = 1;
           flag = false;
        }
        else if( g < r )
           x = 2;
        else
           x = 3;

        switch (x) {
        case (1):
            std::cout << "You won, now get lost!" << std::endl;
            break;
        case (2):
            std::cout << "Too low, piece of turd." << std::endl;
            break;
        case (3):
            std::cout << "Too high, dubai." << std::endl;
            break;
        default :
            std::cout << "How could you possibly have gotten it wrong, you stupid ape." << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: ill try it in a sec! @vjb

Comment: built it, but for some reason it always gives x the value 3 @vjb

Comment: the < signs were inverted! i changed it and now it works perfectly! thanks for the help!! @vjb , also i get the notion that my question wasn´t posted properly, is this so?

Comment: @ Juan If that solves the problem, please mark my post as the answer.  I think some people down voted your question because they expected you to do some more research on your own, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

The switch case checks must be constant expressions that are compared for equality against the original value.

In your case, you can rewrite that **switch** using **if** commands.
Use the code below, and it will compile.

```
if (g == r)
{
    std::cout << "You won, now get lost!" << std::endl;
}
else if (g < r)
{
    std::cout << "Too low, piece of turd." << std::endl;
}
else if (g > r)
{
    std::cout << "Too high, dubai." << std::endl;
} 
else 
{
    // will not get here, as previous if already cover all cases
    std::cout << "How could you possibly have gotten it wrong, you stupid ape." << std::endl;
}
```

C++ switch
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

C++ if
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Comment: Not really answering the question unless you explain why the OP _must_ rewrite the switch to this.

Comment: OP did not ask this. He said "What I want is for it to let the user guess the number as many times as it takes to guess it..."

Comment: He didn't ask that either. There is in fact no question asked at all. If you're going to quote statements as questions, have a look at the title.

Comment: Better now. Add the fact that switch case checks must be expressions that are compared for equality against the original value (rather than being independent conditionals) and you'll get an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to an **if** statement, and now after the first guess, the user isn´t able to guess again.

ok, the new code here:

int main()

{

```
int r = rand() % 101;

int g = 0;

int t = 0;

std::cout << "Guess a number, human (From 1 to 100)." << std::endl;

std::cin >> g;

for (int t = 0; g = r; t++)
{
    if (g < r)
    {
        std::cout << "Too low." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> g;
    }
    else if (g > r)
        std::cout << "Too high." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> g;
}
std::cout << "Finally!, it took you " << t << " freaking times!" << std::endl;


return 0;
```

}

Comment: also, is g = r a valid condition?, by the way, it does compile

Comment: @ Juan You probably want `g==r`

Comment: @vjb right!, or more like, !=, since i want it to run as long as it isn´t equal, right?